Excel or Sheets : Extract unique values
Data table

I have the left table with various values for each name.
I want to have the right table, so that the name gets repeated as many as the number of its existing groups.
In fact, the second column of the result is extracted based on the first column of the result.
I have got no idea how to do this.

UNIQUE function can does it.

As @Blackcat said - =UNIQUE(A2:B15) will give the unique values.  Wrap in SORT to get the same sort order as your example:  =SORT(UNIQUE(A2:B15),{1,2},{1,1})  {1,2} - sort by first and then second column, {1,1} - sort ascending on both columns.

In google sheets you can use sortn: =sortn(A2:B,9^9,2)
